# Removing old code-first migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got a long-lived project with about 15 migrations in it. Realistically, I only need the latest 3 or so -- I'd like to remove many of these.

The first migration has essentially all the initial create table statements in it. All the modifications and additions after it would need to be merged into this, so it isn't quite as simple as just deleting some files and cleaning up the __Migrations table in the database.

Is there a way to remove old migrations?

Comment: You really need to keep some of them ? It would be easier to remove all which is related to migrations, and redo an "Enable migrations", no ? Then you would have a new "First migration" with your actual state.

Comment: I agree with @Raphael. I have done this many times.

Comment: I considered that, but dismissed it due to my environment having multiple versions of the database (prod/stage/dev) in action. That's why I mentioned only needing the latest 3 or so migrations. How are you addressing that?